# Best quality dithering library in C

Tags: c, image-processing, color-palette, dithering

I'm developing a texture atlas packer to use with OpenGL, and I'm currently looking for an open-source (it's better if it's a library, but an open-source software would be good as well!) solution that will render the best results for color palette creation / dithering. It really doesn't need to be fast, but needs to achieve optimal results. It would be best if there is a possibility for 4-bit-per-pixel palette generation.

Comment: I have provided code for Floyd-Steinberg dithering here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17900812/342646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pngquant is available as a pure C library](http://pngquant.org/lib).

ImageMagick [uses octtree](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/quantize.php), which is fast, but not the best quality.

[pngquant](http://pngquant.org) uses MedianCut with several additional improvements, and is likely to give higher quality.

pngquant has speed/quality trade-off setting which can improve quality a bit further, and also has custom dithering algorithm (variation of Floyd-Steinberg) that doesn't add noise to well-quantized areas of the image.

Comment: well, I guess this is a best answer after all! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Imagemagick is a *very powerful* C library for graphical manipulation: http://www.imagemagick.org/ It has commandline tools, but can also be used as a C library.

Comment: Thank you! That will do. One question though, as I really need not the one with most features, but the one with the best dithering algorithm, do you know if their dithering algorithm is any good?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I found [PNGNQ](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/pngnqsamples.html), which is a pretty good library for image quantization. Their samples are amazing.